# jstl condition doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I can't understand how is that possible, so i will just show the code.

This works. As expected, a list of "PAIR" is printed:

```
<c:forEach var="element" items="${list}">
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="true">
       <div>PAIR ${element}</div>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       <div>ODD ${element}</div>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

This doesn't work. Print only "ODD":

```
<c:forEach var="element" items="${list}">
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="true == true">
       <div>PAIR ${element}</div>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       <div>ODD ${element}</div>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the EL literal: `${..}`. Use `test="${true == true}"` and it will work.

The first example works because the string `true`, when converted to boolean, is `true`. The parser tries to convert the string-value you passed to boolean using `Boolean.valueOf(..)`. And a conversion of the `true == true` string, using `Boolean.valueOf(..)` gives you `false`.